# NextJS Auth0: No state or session cookies set when `NODE_ENV` is production and deployed environment is not secure

Tags: ssl, cookies, https, next.js, auth0

When we try to use this library:

https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0

I see the correct cookies being set in `localhost` which is also when `NODE_ENV` is `development`.

When I deploy to our dev environment it is not secure.

During deployment builds the `NODE_ENV` is set to `production` which sets cookies to secure in the `nextjs-auth0` library.

As our dev environment is `http` we are not seeing the relevant cookies set.  Does our environment have to be secure to be able to set secure cookies?